# Error inflating AppWidget after upgrade

Tags: android, widget

I have updated my app to 23 SDK and Android Studio.
And now my home screen widget dissapears on upgrade to new version.
I have investigated logs and saw this warning:

```
W/AppWidgetHostView: Error inflating AppWidget AppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{*********/**********}): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
```

But I did not use ActionMenuView in my widget layout. And I have no ideas how I could use it in widget.

After app upgrade I can add widget again and all looks like good.
I have not had such problems with widget before.

- minSdkVersion 7
- targetSdkVersion 23
- compileSdkVersion 23
- buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0

---

UPDATE:

I have found that ActionMenuView used only in abc_action_menu_layout.xml exploded from compat library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:divider="?attr/actionBarDivider"
    app:dividerPadding="12dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

But I don't understand why it needed for the home screen widget.

Comment: You should put the solution as your own answer, and accept it. It's completely valid in SO

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of this issue.
After Android Studio migration **I have moved my Widget Providers classes to /controller subdirectory**. And this caused widget disappearing after app update.
So, I just moved them back to the root sources directory.